# Responsive design with mobile first and disabled javascript

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm trying to figure out how to streamline my development process for responsive design. The standard way is to design mobile first by using media queries going from mobile to desktop sizes.

The issue I'm seeing is supporting IE7 and IE8. The solution everyone is going to, is to use response.js. What about supporting those who disable javascript? Is there something I'm not seeing?

**EDIT:** I know the its a super small percentage of users that have JS disabled. It's a requirement for this project.

Comment: Unless you _really_ need IE7, I would just stick to IE8+ to ease the pain. Let's move the web forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mobile First follows the path of *Graceful degradation*. To put it simply, "We provide backward support up to this point only, or you get nothing". And for older browsers, you *will* get nothing. This is the path of polyfills, patches and workarounds which is what scripts are trying to do.

On the other hand, *Progressive Enhancement* caters all basic functionality only up to what the browser can do. It's like "We support everything up to the latest which you support". This is what you are trying to do, and what you should be doing.

So let's exploit the fact that CSS is cascading. Initially use a fixed or fluid layout, then the responsive layout. For browsers that don't understand media queries will simply disregard it, leaving your fixed or fluid styles to shine through.

Mobile browsers support media queries or have JS most likely turned on. Wap browsers also live happily with fluid layouts.

---

*For JS, 95% of users have JS on. The other 5% are people that

1. have outdated browsers (Mosaic?)
2. are not desktop browsers at all (crawlers, proxies, scrapers)
3. wap browsers (except some browsers like Opera Mini which run a few JS on load)
4. and paranoid people who fear JS.

*Now, how much of those are *actually a browser*? Most likely #3 and #4. What are the chances that it's IE? 1/3? What's the probability of hitting 1/3 of half of 5% of the population in order to use a pure CSS, no JS approach?

Don't rely on the fact that possibilities exist. Those are extreme situations that in the real world, only happen 1% out of a billion. As people from UX would say: *demographics*.

<sub>*exaggerated estimates</sub>

Comment: This is what I was thinking of but I to not spend the extra time to create a separate stylesheet :/

Answer (score 0):

It's 2013.  If someone has js disabled, they know their web experience is going to suck.  Not just on your site, but everywhere.  It's less than 1% of users, so don't worry about it.  You can/should basically assume js is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a fixed width version at desktop size for older IE's using conditional comments for an ie.css sheet. (See http://html5boilerplate.com/ for a great example of this)

Respond.js often runs really slowly and is far harder to debug then "traditional fixed width" IE 7,8. So it's way more work to support (even if it weren't part of your project requirements to support non-js users).

*Thing about it from the end user's perspective.* If I needed to borrow grandma's beige tower running IE 7, I'd rather have a faster, fixed-width site then a buggy, slow responsive site. Also these are old computers with users used to fixed width sites anyways.

Also consider looking into using SASS to help with the breakpoint madness. My favorite mixin is "Breakpoint". Check out their documentation here related to supporting browsers that don't support media queries. In short you add a variable to a media query to see "export to my IE.css = true" then these become the core components of your ie.css sheet and there's less custom IE work to do.

https://github.com/Team-Sass/breakpoint/wiki/No-Query-Fallbacks